# Linking input info from userform to cells

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm creating a multipage userform where the user inputs data into textboxes and selects from combo boxes, option buttons, etc. I have a data sheet that has formulas in the cells and I'm trying to link what the user inputs in the userform to cells in a spreadsheet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would add a button something like "SAVE", and add a macro to that (double-click it in the VBE), and inside there you can write something like `range("A3").value=me.textbox1` where `A3` is the location you want to write to, and `textbox1` would be the thing in your userform you want to write into excel.

Answer (score 0):

Userform can be achieved using excel vba. Then run it on excel macro and post the values of textbox from excel vba userform to cells.

For example:
`Range("A4").Value = Me.txtAmount.Value` - From Userform textbox to Cells
`Range("A4").EntireColumn.AutoFit` -Autofit Column of the displayed cell values.